# How can I check if the user is logged in with a graphical session AND that the same user is executing the script

Tags: bash, scripts, gui, gsettings

I have a bash script that among other things uses the `gsettings` command. It seems to me that in order for this command to work the user has to be logged in with a graphical session, and obviously, also has to execute the script as themselves (i.e. not root).

I could check if they're using a graphical terminal by looking at the TERM variable, but how can I make sure the executioner of the script is the same user who is logged in with a graphical session?

Answer (score 2):

- To check **who is logged in** you can use [`who`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/who.1.html).
- To check **which user ran the script**:

  ```
  ps aux | grep $0 | awk '{ print $1 }' | uniq
  ```

  `ps aux` : Lists all the running processes including the respective user on the first column.

  `grep $0` : Searches for the current script

  `awk '{ print $1 }'`: Prints only what's in the first column

  `uniq`: Removes possible duplicates
- **To check whether the user who ran the script is the same as the user loged in**:

  ```
  LOGED_USER=$(who | awk '{ print $1 }') 
  EXEC_USER=$(ps aux | grep $0 | awk '{ print $1 }' | uniq)

  if [ $LOGED_USER == $EXEC_USER ]; then
        echo "Same USER"
  else 
        echo "Different USER"
  fi
  ```

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear, but `whoami` is not enough. I need to know what user is logged in to the X server (i.e. running gnome/unity/something else) and I need to check that this user is executing the script as themselves.

Comment: What about `who`